# How to zoom an image without the size

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I want to zoom an image but I don't want to care about the size of the image. This widget is for wrapping any widget. The widget I transform is somewhere I don't know. That's why I add 220 to be visible. Could someone enhance my code to be adaptive for any size of widget?

[image]

```
class ZoomDetailPhoto extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const ZoomDetailPhoto({Key? key, required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ZoomDetailPhotoState createState() => _ZoomDetailPhotoState();
}

class _ZoomDetailPhotoState extends State<ZoomDetailPhoto> {
  late Offset offset;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    offset = Offset.zero;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    return Listener(
      onPointerHover: (onPointerHover) {
        setState(() {
          offset = onPointerHover.localPosition;
        });
      },
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          widget.child,
          Positioned(
            left: offset.dx - 90,
            top: offset.dy - 90,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                      width: 9, color: theme.colorScheme.onBackground)),
              child: Container(
                  width: 180,
                  height: 180,
                  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(),
                  child: FittedBox(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      child: Transform.scale(
                          scale: 4,
                          child: Transform.translate(
                              offset:
                                  Offset(-offset.dx + 220, -offset.dy + 220),
                              child: widget.child)))),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the size of the child, you can use a `GlobalKey` and assign it to the child (image or whatever widget), then in your `Listener` (you can probably use `MouseRegion` instead of `Listener`, similar purpose, slightly easier to use) you can get the size of its child widget using `GlobalKey`.

Note, however, a widget's size can only be determined after it has finished the layout process. If you don't mind lagging one frame behind, you can just do the magnifier effect with a `Stack` (what you are doing currently) in the next frame. Otherwise, you can consider using an `OverlayEntry` to do the magnifier instead, because overlays are built in a separate flow after normal widgets.

Note on the previous note, I personally wouldn't mind lagging one frame in this particular case, because the magnifier only shows up when the user hovers it, so skipping 1 frame when the page is first loaded won't be noticeable.

---

**Edit:**

This question is pretty interesting to me, and I just thought of another way to get a child's size in the same frame: use `Positioned.fill` in a `Stack`, no `GlobalKey` or `Overlay` needed. Using this idea, I  made a widget to do this.

[image: demo]

**Usage:**

```
 Magnifier(
    magnification: 2.0,
    child: Scaffold(
       ...
```

**Source:**

```
class Magnifier extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final double magnification;

  const Magnifier({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    this.magnification = 2.0,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MagnifierState createState() => _MagnifierState();
}

class _MagnifierState extends State<Magnifier> {
  Offset? _offset;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        widget.child,
        Positioned.fill(
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (_, BoxConstraints constraints) {
              final childSize = constraints.biggest;
              return MouseRegion(
                onHover: (event) {
                  setState(() => _offset = event.localPosition);
                },
                onExit: (_) => setState(() => _offset = null),
                child: _offset != null
                    ? _buildBox(_offset!.dx, _offset!.dy, childSize)
                    : null,
              );
            },
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBox(double dx, double dy, Size childSize) {
    final magnifierSize = childSize.shortestSide / 2;
    return Transform.translate(
      offset: Offset(dx - magnifierSize / 2, dy - magnifierSize / 2),
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: magnifierSize,
              height: magnifierSize,
              child: ClipRect(
                child: Transform.scale(
                  scale: widget.magnification,
                  child: Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset(
                      childSize.width / 2 - dx,
                      childSize.height / 2 - dy,
                    ),
                    child: OverflowBox(
                      minWidth: childSize.width,
                      maxWidth: childSize.width,
                      minHeight: childSize.height,
                      maxHeight: childSize.height,
                      child: widget.child,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned.fill(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 2),
                  color: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.2),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very munch. I understand more things and that's wonderful!!

Comment: You have an excellente level in Flutter. If you could anwser my previous question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71468925/how-to-transform-a-widget-by-switching-view , Easy for you no?